# Is there a script that checks links from a list and determines if they are working?

Tags: if-statement, url, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of about 200 URLs and I want to check whether they are working or bring an error. Is there a script or a formula I can use that can show me whether a link is broken?

Comment: @PierreAvinain yeah of course I did, I used some of the scripts and formulas I found but they are bringing errors

Comment: did you found this one? https://medium.com/@the.benhawy/how-to-use-google-spreadsheets-to-check-for-broken-links-1bb0b35c8525

Comment: yeah it wasn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
function URLCHECK(url){
   var options = {
     'muteHttpExceptions': true,
     'followRedirects': false
   };
   var url_trimmed = url.trim();
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_trimmed, options);
   return response.getResponseCode();
}
```

and formula:

```
=IF(URLCHECK(A2)>=400, "broken", "ok")
```

[image: 0]